# Australia - Travel-Work Visa -- What are the limitations?

Tags: visa, working-visas, australia

So essentially, I'm looking at the possibilities to working within Australia as a permanent resident. I have done a lot of research into the skilled visa, and, although this does sound like what I need, the cost and time it takes may be a little off-putting.

Essentially, I want to move to Australia within the next few months. If, I apply for a skilled visa, more than likely I would have to make a Expression of Interest, then submit my visa and finally wait to be sponsored. If I cannot find a sponsor, this would be very timely. My occupation is on the list of skills that are in high demand, and also I have enough points to secure a visa, but this does not mean you can just enter Australia to look for work.

So.. I have read about the "Work Travel Visas" but these seem to be around people who are backpacking and who want jobs, rather than careers. My aim is to continue my career, but do it in Australia.

My question is: Let's say I applied for a Working holiday visa, found a job that is within my career then after my probation, if I like the city and the job then I will apply for a skilled visa to give me permanent resident in a hope that the company offers me a full, permanent contract and sponsorship. Is this allowed on the "working holiday visa" or is this visa just for backpackers who want to seek less permanent jobs and want to travel?

P.S. The main attraction of the working holiday visa, I could potentially find a contract based job for around 3-6 months, with a hope to be more permanent. Also, if the experience does not work out, I haven't spent over $3000AUD on a skilled visa.